# Infinite regular languages

Tags: automata, regular-language

There is a formal proof for the following sentence?

> For every 2 languages $A,B$, we write A@B if A subset of B and B\A infinite. Prove that if $A,B$ regular languages and A@b, than exists regular language $C$ such that A@C@B.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are regular languages, so is $B\setminus A$, so the problem really boils down to showing that if $L$ is an infinite regular language, there is an infinite regular language $L'@L$.

HINT: Let $p$ be the pumping length for $L$, and let $w\in L$ be any word of length at least $p$. Decompose $w$ as $w=xyz$, where $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. Take $L'$ to be a suitable subset of $\{xy^kz:k\ge 0\}$.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. I can take L' to be an even k? that way L' is an infinite regular language and subset of L. If I understood the lemma correctly, i can take two languages L1 and L2 such that L1UL2 = L and L1 is and equal pumping times and L2 is odd pumping times.

Comment: @automata123: You’re very welcome. Yes, that’s exactly the subset that I had in mind.